# Best Data Structure to Store Large Amounts of Data with Dynamic and Non-unique Keys?

Tags: data-structures

Basically, I have a large number of C structs to keep track of, that are essentially:

```
struct Data {
    int key;
    ...        // More data
};
```

I need to periodically access lots (hundreds) of these, and they must be sorted from lowest to highest `key` values. The keys are not unique and they will be changed over the course of the program. To make matters even more interesting, the majority of the structures will be culled (based on criteria completely unrelated to the key values) from the pool right before being sorted, but I still need to keep references to them.

I've looked into using a binary search tree to store them, but the keys are not guaranteed to be unique and I'm not entirely sure how to restructure the tree once a key is changed or how to cull specific structures.

To recap in case that was unclear above, I need to:

1. Store a large number of structures with non-unique and dynamic keys.
2. Cull a large percentage of the structures (but not free them entirely because different structures are culled each time).
3. Sort the remaining structures from highest to lowest key value.

What data structure/algorithms would you use to solve this problem? The method needs to be as fast and/or memory efficient as possible, since this is a real-time application.

EDIT: The culling is done by iterating over all of the objects and making a decision for each one. The keys change between the culling/sorting runs. I should have stated that they don't change a lot, but they do change, and they can change multiple times between the culling/sorting runs. (If it helps, the key for each structure is actually a z-order for a Sprite. They need to be sorted before each drawing loop so the Sprites with lower z-orders are drawn first.)

Comment: It would help to know how often the keys change: in the time between cull/sort runs, what fraction of the keys have changed? Would they have changed more than once?

Comment: Also, how is the culling done? Do you iterate over all the objects and make a decision about each one?

Comment: You can certainly implement a binary tree where keys are guaranteed to be unique.  Upon insertion, you have to descend the tree anyway, so when you get to where the new key goes, make sure the key at the insertion point isn't equal to the one you're inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick 'em all in a big array.

When the time comes to do the cull and sort, start by doing the sort. Do an insertion sort. That's right - nothing clever, just an insertion sort.

After the sort, go through the sorted array, and for each object, make the culling decision, then immediately output the object if it isn't culled.

This is about as memory-efficient as it gets. It should also require very little computation: there's no bookkeeping on updates between cull/sort passes, and the sort will be cheap - because insertion sort is adaptive, and for an almost-sorted array like this, it will be almost O(n). The one thing it doesn't do is cache locality: there will be two separate passes over the array, for the sort, and the cull/output.

If you demand more cleverness, then instead of an insertion sort, you could use another adaptive, in-place sort that's faster. Timsort and smoothsort are good candidates; both are utterly fiendish to implement.

The big alternative to this is to only sort unculled objects, using a secondary, temporary, list of such objects which you sort (or keep in a binary tree or whatever). But the thing is, if the keys don't change that much, then the win you get from using an adaptive sort on an almost-sorted array will (i reckon!) outweigh the win you would get from sorting a smaller dataset. It's O(n) vs O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to this type of problem is to use a balanced search tree (e.g. AVL tree, red-black tree, B-tree), which guarantees O(log n) time (almost constant, but not quite) for insertion, deletion, and lookup, where n is the number of items currently stored in the tree.  Guaranteeing no key is stored in the tree twice is quite trivial, and is done automatically by many implementations.

If you're working in C++, you could try using `std::map<int, yourtype>`.  If in C, find or implement some simple binary search tree code, and see if it's fast enough.

However, if you use such a tree and find it's too slow, you could look into some more fine-tuned approaches.  One might be to put your structs in one big array, [radix sort](http://www.cubic.org/docs/radix.htm) by the integer key, cull on it, then re-sort per pass.  Another approach might be to use a Patricia tree.